# Loop over types in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a  way to loop over the custom types in flutter.

```
class Square {}

class Rectangle {}

getShape<T>() {
  if(T is Square) {
    return Square();
  }
}

void main() {
  
  List shapes = [Square, Rectangle];
  
  for (dynamic T in shapes) {
    getShape<T>();
  }
}
```

In the above code, T is not getting identified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```dart
class Square {}

class Rectangle {}

getShape(T) {
  print(T is Rectangle);
  if(T is Square) {
    return Square();
  }
}

void main() {
  
  List shapes = [Square(), Rectangle()];
  
  for (dynamic T in shapes) {
    getShape(T);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code produces this diagnostic because T is a variable, not a type:
[Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#non_type_as_type_argument)

Either you can send it as the Function argument
`getShape(T){}`

or

`getShape<T>(){}`
then

```
for (final T in shapes) {
    if (T == Square) {
      print(getShape<Square>());
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my case, I have 32 such different types. I was looking for a way, where I don't have to type so many lines of code. Could there be any way to loop over types and use them? (For example, create list or call a common method defined for those classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do a lot of useful things with `Type` objects.  You can, however, use them as keys in a `Map`:

```dart
class Square {}

class Rectangle {}

final shapeFactories = <Type, dynamic Function()>{
  Square: () => Square(),
  Rectangle: () => Rectangle(),
};

void main() {
  var shapes = <Type>[Square, Rectangle];
  
  for (var T in shapes) {
    var shape = shapeFactories[T]!();
    print(shape.runtimeType);
  }
}
```